# Casting user define type back to tuple

Tags: f#, f#-data

I am new to F#. I am working with a custom type which contains tuples.

```
type myType = 
    | obj1 of int * int
    | obj2 of string * string
```

Now I have function which yields the sequence of this `myType`

```
type Response = XmlProvider<"""<Result><ns7:value>Item 1</ns7:value>`<ns7:status>1</ns7:status></Result>""", Global=true>`

let comparison (a:Response.Result) (b::Response.Result) = seq {
    if a.Status <> b.Status then 
        yield Status(a.Value, a.Status, b.Status)
}
```

After that I get the array of `myType`

```
let a = """<Result><ns7:value>Item 1</ns7:value>`<ns7:status>1</ns7:status></Result>"""
let b = """<Result><ns7:value>Item 1</ns7:value>`<ns7:status>1</ns7:status></Result>"""
let compareResults = comparison  a b |> Seq.toArray
```

My question is when a traverse through `compareResults`, how can I get back tuple `obj1` and `obj2`. Currently all I am getting is the object of `myType`. Is there a way to cast that back into a tuple?

> **Update**

```
module Script.File1

open System
open FSharp.Data
open HttpClient

type myType = 
    | Obj1 of string * int * int
    | Obj2 of string * string

type Response = XmlProvider<"""<Result><value>Item 1</value><status>1</status></Result>""", Global=true>

let comparison (a:Response.Result) (b:Response.Result) = seq {
    if a.Status <> b.Status then 
        yield Obj1(a.Value, a.Status, b.Status)
}

let a = Response.Parse("""<Result><value>Item 1</value><status>1</status></Result>""")
let b = Response.Parse("""<Result><value>Item 1</value><status>1</status></Result>""")
let compareResults = comparison  a b |> Seq.toArray

let run () =
    for c in compareResults do
        printfn " - %O" c
```

Comment: Since `myType` is a discrimated union it can contain either obj1 or obj2. In most cases you would want to [pattern match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching) on value of that type handling each case separately.

Comment: @3615 Is there no way to access the tuple directly after getting the type. I mean I can get the type of `compareResults` using `compareResultsItem.GetType().Name`

Comment: The code in your question is not well-typed - What is `a` and `b` in your `comparison` function and what is the `Status` constructor in `yield Status(...)`. Without this, it's hard to see what you're asking.

Comment: @mjosh there are multiple ways to get the values, but, as stated above, your code is too abstract to suggest a concrete solution. Most common way to get values from a discrimated union is pattern matching. You can see it in action in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9oT4ek).

Comment: @TomasPetricek I updated the code. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: It doesn't compile.

Comment: What @BentTranberg said. You need to fix compile-time errors first (make `obj1` and `obj2` upper case, fix the invalid XML and define `Status`).

Comment: @BentTranberg check the update

Comment: @TomasPetricek Yep, I fixed all those errors.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have something like this (to start with a simplified compilable example):

```
type MyType = 
  | Obj1 of int * int
  | Obj2 of string * string

let demo = seq {
  for i in 0 .. 9 do
    yield Obj1(i, i) }
```

Now, `demo` is a sequence of `MyType` values that all happen to be `Obj1`. You can pattern match on the values, but you will need to cover both of the cases, because the compiler does not know that all values in the sequence all `Obj1`:

```
for d in demo do  
  match d with 
  | Obj1(i1, i2) -> printfn "%d %d" i1 i2
  | _ -> failwith "Should not happen"
```

If you want to avoid this, you could just yield a pair of integers so that the type of `demo` is `seq<int * int>`. Then you can iterate over that easily or you can wrap it into `Obj1` when needed.

Alternatively, you could change your type definition so that the value is a tuple (wrapped with extra parentheses) rather than just two elements:

```
type MyType = 
  | Obj1 of (int * int)
  | Obj2 of (string * string)
```

Now you can more easily pass the `int * int` value around. For example:

```
let demo = seq {
  for i in 0 .. 9 do
    yield i, i }

// Turn sequence of tuples into `MyType`
let objs = Seq.map Obj1 demo

// Iterate over a sequence of tuples
for i1, i2 in demo do  
  printfn "%d %d" i1 i2
```